# Why can't I connect to my Flask server after it's deployed in a Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have created a Flask web-app that serves some static files, and it works just fine locally. I now want to create a Docker image for it and run a container where I can access it.

Running:
`python server.py` 
Works fine and I can access the application at http://localhost:5000/

I created a Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python server.py
EXPOSE 8082
```

When I run:
`docker run -p 8082:5000 emotional`
it outputs that it's running and everything is working fine within the container.

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
```

but when I navigate to http://localhost:8082 I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, and when I try http://localhost:5000 (which I know isn't supposed to work) it gives ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 0):

You should expose port 5000 in your dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 5000
```

Comment: This doesn't work, and also didn't change the output of the original problem.

Comment: Expose the port before running your server.py.